# Nodejs: I want to get values from a callback URL using get method

Tags: node.js, parameters, callbackurl

This is my redirect/callback URL:
http://localhost:3000/users/servicespage/callback?payment_id=MOJO7717005A25534569&payment_request_id=378e45f1a7d944299a5185a9eea29c83

I want to have values of:

**payment_id**       :  MOJO7717005A25534569

**payment_request_id**  :  378e45f1a7d944299a5185a9eea29c83

I am new to Nodejs and trying to use below approach, but it works only for 1st value when '**?**' sign is not there, so basically below approach is not giving any result:

```
router.get('/callback/:payment_id',function(req,res)
{
console.log(req.params.payment_id);
return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is query string but not URL matching.

```
router.get('/callback',function(req,res)
{
console.log(req.query.payment_id);
console.log(req.query.payment_request_id );
return;
}
```

Comment: Hi subaru710, thanks for your help, can you provide me some links/resources where I can read more about them.

Comment: Hi killmal, if you're using express, here is the API reference: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html, which includes the information about req.query. And you can also find some tutorial on that website.

Answer (score 1):

`/callback/:payment_id` route means all the url with `/callback/ANY`.

but you want to query string data and `/callback` url

```
const url = require('url');
router.get('/callback',function(req,res)
{     
   const query = (url.parse(req.url, true)).query; // get query string data
   console.log(query);
   // ......
}
```

https://scotch.io/tutorials/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4